# Selenium JavaScriptExecutor click function works only first time

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

On the UI I have a checkAll button which is implemented as a span under a div block. clicking it become hard so I used JavaScriptExcutor. I want click it two times. the code is as following 6 lines. the line3 always succeeded, but line 6 always fail silently (no error or exception, but click not happening). if I comment out line 3 then line 6 will function. why? please help me.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)drv;
IWebElement chkAll = TaskerStatus.FindElement(By.Id("header3-column0"));
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", chkAll);

cmdBar1collapseAll.Click();
expandAllBtn.Click();
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", chkAll);
```

Comment: I duplicate a line of line 6 (as line 7) then it worked. don't understand why line 6 is now working but has to be there to make line seven work.

Comment: correct a mistake in above comment: line 6 is now= line 6 is not

Comment: What if you target the element in the js: `document.getElementById('header3-column0').click()`

Comment: Hi pguardiario, I tried your suggestion. nothing changes. Thanks anyway. I think I figured out the root cause.

Comment: Ok good. You should answer your own question in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood the *usecase* / *issue* properly, *Line 6* i.e.:

```
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", chkAll);
```

**fails** silently, i.e. no error or exception and the `click()` not happening as well.

But again if you comment out `line 3` i.e. the first instance of:

```
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", chkAll);
```

Then `line 6` i.e. the second instance of:

```
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", chkAll);
```

functions well.

The reason *Line 6* is failing because when you invoked `click()` on the *IWebElement* **chkAll** a *JavaScript* / *jQuery* might have been active.

### Solution

You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *IWebElement* **chkAll** to be **clickable** before you invoke the click at *Line 6* and you can update *Line 6* as follows:

```
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(TaskerStatus.FindElement(By.Id("header3-column0")))));
```

Comment: Hi DebanijanB, Thank you for your suggestion. I tried your code. it throw a Timeoutexception. it also said the function of ExpectedContidtion is obsoleted. but I know what you mean. the timing sometimes is a problem. I figured out the root cause now. it is because the line4 code. This internal implementation caused the human eye didn't see the button click effect. but it actually did. I have a workaround to resolve it. but Thank you.